# Update document fields using Sanity.io CLI

Tags: json, command-line-interface, sanity, ndjson

I want to bulk update a single field on 100+ documents of the same document type.

With the goal of keeping my import file as slim as possible, I want to just be able to include the _id and the key/value pair of the field I am updating, rather than having to include all the existing k/v pairs.

Using the `sanity dataset import` function with the --replace flag, the current document matching the given _id will be completely overwritten and populated with the k/v pairs of the import file (nulling out any fields that were previously populated in the document but were omitted from the import file).

Has anyone found a convenient way to only update the fields present in the import file rather than having to populate the import file with all the existing k/v pairs?

Thanks!

p.s this is my first post on here. Please let me know if my question needs any clarification.